# Get SharePoint People Picker Data Using REST API

Tags: jquery, rest, sharepoint

I am working in SharePoint 2013 and I am writing a REST API call to a list to retrieve field data, which among other things, includes a People field. I'm not having problems retrieving the field in the query, but I'm having issues displaying that field in the subsequent Dynamic HTML.

Here is the Field information:

- Field Display Name: Regulatory Partner
- Field Internal Name: Regulatory_x0020_Partner

Here is the REST API query string:

```
url: "/sites/regulatory3/testdashboard/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Contacts')/items?$select=Regulatory_x0020_Partner/ID,Regulatory_x0020_Partner/FirstName,Regulatory_x0020_Partner/LastName&$expand=Regulatory_x0020_Partner/ID",
```

Here is the display code:

```
"<td><td class='columns1'>" + value.Regulatory_x0020_Partner.FirstName + "</td><td class='columns1'>"
```

When run here is how the output appears:

undefined

Here's what I've tried so far:

- Regulatory_x0020_Partner/ID
- Regulatory_x0020_Partner/FirstName
- Regulatory_x0020_Partner/LastName

All the same results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, this is weird! Essentially the issue was the space in the field name. While REST API handles spaces in other fields like this - `My_x0020_Field`, when you use the same approach with a Person field - `My_x0020_Person`, it doesn't work. So when I created a new Person field, and instead of naming it - `Regulatory_x0020_Partner` - I named it `RegulatoryPartner` and everything worked fine!

Anybody else ever seen this quirk when working with SharePoint, REST API and People Fields with spaces in them?

Answer (score 0):

'$Select' is missing from your rest endpoint, the endpoint should look like this：'/sites/regulatory3/testdashboard/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Contacts')/items?"$select=Regulatory_x0020_Partner/ID,Regulatory_x0020_Partner/FirstName,Regulatory_x0020_Partner/LastName&$expand=Regulatory_x0020_Partner'

Here is my test code for you reference:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function() {
                getUser()
} )
function getUser(){

   $.ajax({  
                                url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('dsds')/items?$select=Regulatory_x0020_Partner/FirstName,Regulatory_x0020_Partner/LastName,Regulatory_x0020_Partner/EMail,Regulatory_x0020_Partner/UserName&$expand=Regulatory_x0020_Partner/Id",  
                                type: "GET",  
                                headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },  


                                success: function(data) {  
                                   //console.log(data.d.results); 
                                                for(var i = 0;i<data.d.results.length;i++)   {
                                                                console.log("FirstName:"+data.d.results[i].Regulatory_x0020_Partner.FirstName);
                                                                console.log("LastName:"+data.d.results[i].Regulatory_x0020_Partner.LastName);
                                                                console.log("EMail:"+data.d.results[i].Regulatory_x0020_Partner.EMail);
                                                                console.log("UserName:"+data.d.results[i].Regulatory_x0020_Partner.UserName);
                                                                console.log("--------------------------------")
                }                              
                                },  
                                error: function(error) {  
                                                //alert(JSON.stringify(error));  
                                }  
                })
}
</script>
```

Comment: You're right Lee, but that was just a copying error. In my working code the `$select=` statement is there, and other fields are returned, but the problem is that when the People field - "Regulatory_x0020_Partner" displays, it is "undefined". I've corrected my original post to better represent the actual code.